# How do I add onClick behavior to a Cesium PointPrimitive in a Resium PointPrimitiveCollection?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, onclicklistener, cesiumjs, resium

I want pointPrimitives that I add to a map to have onClick behavior.
Resium pointPrimitives have onClick behavior when added as children to a PointPrimitiveCollection.
Plain old Cesium PointPrimitives do not have onClick behavior.
This may be a Cesium/Resium thing or a React thing.

- Tried adding points using PointPrimitiveCollection.add that already have onClick methods defined.
- Tried adding points using PointPrimitiveCollection.add() and then adding an onClick method after.
- Tried adding JSX using PointPrimitiveCollection.add()
- because state gets too large in my application, I cannot add points using useState
  Here's the minimal example of what I've tried:

```
import { PointPrimitive, PointPrimitiveCollection, Viewer, useCesiumComponent } from 'resium';
import { Cartesian3, Color, PointPrimitiveCollection as PPC } from 'cesium';
import { useRef } from 'react';

const ingestStream = () => {
    const collectionRef = useRef(null);
    let pc: any;

    const addPoints = (pt) => {
        console.log('adding')
        if (pc === undefined) {
            if (collectionRef.current && collectionRef.current.cesiumElement) {
                pc = collectionRef.current.cesiumElement;
                globalThis.pointColl = pc;
                //TODO: add the else{} contents here when done editing them
            }
        } else {
            //adds point normally, ignores onClick
            pc.add({
                position: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(pt.LON, pt.LAT+2, pt.ALT_GEOM),
                color: { red: 1, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1 },
                pixelSize: 60,
                onClick: () => {console.log('ow, clickage')},
            })
            
            //Adds onClick, but onClick does not fire with clicks
            const e = pc.add({
                position: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(pt.LON, pt.LAT, pt.ALT_GEOM),
                color: { red: 1, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1 },
                pixelSize: 60,
                }
            );
            e.onClick = () => console.log('touched point')

            //adds point to (0,0,0) without onClick
            pc.add(JSXPoint_added)
            
        }
    };

    const ptconst = {
        LON: -80,
        LAT:43,
        ALT_GEOM: 100
    }

    const clickHandler = () => addPoints(ptconst)
    
    const JSXPoint_added = <PointPrimitive 
        position={ Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-77, 43, 100)} 
        color={Color.CYAN}
        pixelSize={30}
        onClick={clickHandler}
    />

    //onClick works, but there's no obvious reason when I inspect the PointPrimitiveCollection
    //or when I inspect PointPrimitiveCollection.get(0)
    const original = <PointPrimitive 
        position={ Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75, 43, 100)} 
        color={Color.CYAN}
        pixelSize={30}
        onClick={clickHandler}
    />
    
    

    return (
        <Viewer
                id="resiumContainer"
                full
                baseLayerPicker={false}
                geocoder={false}
                animation={false}
                timeline={false}
                navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible={false}
            >
            <PointPrimitiveCollection  ref={collectionRef}>
                {original}
            </PointPrimitiveCollection>

        </Viewer>

    );
};

export default ingestStream;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ScreenSpaceEventHandler!

There's a little bit of hairiness between using resium and ceisum imports, and this solution IS not optimal code, but it's the best technique for this problem. ScreenSpaceEventHandler can tell you which object on Cesium's canvas the user clicks. If the clicked object has a unique ID, you can execute an arbitrary callback function based on the clicked object. Here's an example using your code

```
import { PointPrimitive, PointPrimitiveCollection, Viewer, useCesiumComponent } from 'resium';
import { Cartesian3, Color, PointPrimitiveCollection as PPC, ScreenSpaceEventHandler, ScreenSpaceEventType, defined as CesiumDefined} from 'cesium';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const ingestStream = () => {
    const collectionRef = useRef(null);
    const viewRef = useRef(null);
    let pc: any;

    const addPoints = (pt) => {
        console.log('adding')
        if (pc === undefined) {
            if (collectionRef.current && collectionRef.current.cesiumElement) {
                pc = collectionRef.current.cesiumElement;
                globalThis.pointColl = pc;
                //TODO: add the else{} contents here when done editing them
            }
        } else {
            //adds point normally, ignores onClick
            pc.add({
                position: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(pt.LON, pt.LAT+2, pt.ALT_GEOM),
                color: { red: 1, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1 },
                pixelSize: 60,
                onClick: () => {console.log('ow, clickage')},
                id: 'uniqueID'
            })
            
            //Adds onClick, but onClick does not fire with clicks
            const e = pc.add({
                position: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(pt.LON, pt.LAT, pt.ALT_GEOM),
                color: { red: 1, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1 },
                pixelSize: 60,
                }
            );
            e.onClick = () => console.log('touched point')

            //adds point to (0,0,0) without onClick
            pc.add(JSXPoint_added)
            
        }
    };

    const ptconst = {
        LON: -80,
        LAT:43,
        ALT_GEOM: 100
    }

    const clickHandler = () => addPoints(ptconst)
    
    const JSXPoint_added = <PointPrimitive 
        position={ Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-77, 43, 100)} 
        color={Color.CYAN}
        pixelSize={30}
        onClick={clickHandler}
    />

    //onClick works, but there's no obvious reason when I inspect the PointPrimitiveCollection
    //or when I inspect PointPrimitiveCollection.get(0)
    const original = <PointPrimitive 
        position={ Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75, 43, 100)} 
        color={Color.CYAN}
        pixelSize={30}
        onClick={clickHandler}
    />
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('rendered')

    let handler;
    if (viewRef.current){
        console.log('making a listener')
        handler = new ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewRef.current.cesiumElement.scene.canvas);
        handler.setInputAction(function(click) {
            const pickedObject = viewRef.current.cesiumElement.scene.pick(click.position);
            if (CesiumDefined(pickedObject) && pickedObject.id === 'uniqueID'){
                console.log(pickedObject.id)
            }
            console.log(pickedObject)
        }, ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);
    
    }
    }, [
        //destroy the listener here
    ]); 
    
    
    

    return (
        <Viewer
                id="resiumContainer"
                full
                baseLayerPicker={false}
                geocoder={false}
                animation={false}
                timeline={false}
                navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible={false}
                ref={viewRef}
            >
            <PointPrimitiveCollection  ref={collectionRef}>
                {original}
            </PointPrimitiveCollection>

        </Viewer>

    );
};

export default ingestStream;
```